# Convenient GWT-compatible libraries for XML processing

Tags: java, xml, gwt, dom

Built-in XMLParser is a bit too unwieldy for me to use, are there any GWT-compatible client XML processing libraries that are as convenient to use as dom4j or JDOM? 
No Xpath, XSLT support, no mapping to objects is necessary, just plain DOM operations. 
I'm looking for a pure Java solution, not for a JSNI wrapped js library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for a pure Java solution, not for a JSNI wrapped js library.

GWT client side can only run code which is x-compilable to JS:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html

I used this lib very lightly, but seems ok:

http://code.google.com/p/totoe/

If your operations take place on the server, it's your lucky day as you can use whatever Java library you want.

Comment: I meant that I want a Java library that gets translated into JavaScript, not a wrapper around some existing JavaScript library (like GWTQuery) via JSNI. That would make debugging in development mode easier.

Comment: Isn't this enough for you ;http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/xml/client/XMLParser.html

Comment: The point of my question is that this API is somewhat unconvenient and inadequate, since it's just like vanilla DOM API. I'm look for more refined API like jdom or dom4j, but runnable in gwt client mode.

Comment: Edited, try it at your own risk and please let me know if any good as I will have the same question a few weeks :)